# select list disabling going wrong

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, onchange

I'm trying to achieve the following functionality:

If you select from first or second list [data-select="practise"],[data-select="law"] then disable third and fourth list [data-select="other"]

or

If you select from third or fourth list [data-set="other"] then disable all [data-set="default"] except the one selected

The problem I am having is that if you change first and second [data-select="practise"],[data-select="law"] then change one of those back to default, the selects [data-select="other"] become disabled even though one of the first two is still selected.

HTML

```
<fieldset>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="beta-filter1">Practice</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="beta-filter1" data-set="default" data-select="practise">
            <option label="Please select" value="">Please select</option>
            <option label="Excepturi saepe" value="excepturi">Excepturi saepe</option>
            <option label="Asperiores" value="asperiores">Asperiores</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="beta-filter2">Area of Law</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="beta-filter2" data-set="default" data-select="law">
            <option label="Please select" value="">Please select</option>
            <option label="Excepturi saepe" value="excepturi">Excepturi saepe</option>
            <option label="Asperiores" value="asperiores">Asperiores</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="beta-filter3">Practice Region</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="beta-filter3" data-set="default" data-select="other">
            <option label="Please select" value="">Please select</option>
            <option label="Excepturi saepe" value="excepturi">Excepturi saepe</option>
            <option label="Asperiores" value="asperiores">Asperiores</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="beta-filter4">Industry</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="beta-filter4" data-set="default" data-select="other">
            <option label="Please select" value="">Please select</option>
            <option label="Excepturi saepe" value="excepturi">Excepturi saepe</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="beta-filter5">Office</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="beta-filter5">
            <option label="Please select" value="">Please select</option>
            <option label="Excepturi saepe" value="excepturi">Excepturi saepe</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="beta-filter6">Law School (optional)</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="beta-filter6">
            <option label="Please select" value="">Please select</option>
            <option label="Excepturi saepe" value="excepturi">Excepturi saepe</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="beta-filter7">Date (optional)</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="beta-filter7">
            <option label="Please select" value="">Please select</option>
            <option label="Excepturi saepe" value="excepturi">Excepturi saepe</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

JS

```
$('select').change(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $myVal = $this.val();
    var $defaultSelect = ('[data-set="default"]');
    var $otherSelect = ('[data-select="other"]');
    var $mySelect = $this.attr('data-select');

    if($mySelect === 'practise' || $mySelect === 'law') {
        var $others = $this.closest('fieldset').find($otherSelect);
        compare();
    } else if ($mySelect === 'other') {
        var $others = $this.closest('fieldset').find($defaultSelect).not($this);
        compare();
    }
    function compare() {
        if ($myVal !== '') {
            $others.prop('disabled',true);
        } else {
            $others.prop('disabled',false);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: try this : `compare($myVal);` `function compare($myVal) {`

Comment: when you disable could clear values using `val()` with an empty string

Comment: none of the above working :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified your javascript to:

```
$('select').change(function() {
    var self = $(this);
    var myVal = self.val();
    var selPractice = $('[data-select="practise"]');
    var selLaw = $('[data-select="law"]');
    var defaultSelect = $('[data-set="default"]');
    var otherSelect = $('[data-select="other"]');
    var mySelect = self.attr('data-select');

    if(mySelect === 'practise' || mySelect === 'law') {
        var others = self.closest('fieldset').find(otherSelect);
        if (selPractice.val() == '' && selLaw.val()=='' ) {
            others.prop('disabled',false);
        }
        else {
            others.prop('disabled',true);
        }

    } else if (mySelect === 'other') {
        var others = self.closest('fieldset').find(defaultSelect).not(self);
        compare();
    }
    function compare() {        
        if (myVal !=='') {
            others.prop('disabled',true);
        } else {
            others.prop('disabled',false);
        }
    }
});
```

you can also find a working fiddle at: http://jsfiddle.net/qppa4qpe/16/

Comment: I can see it working in the fiddle but for some reason it isn't working for me. Looks like i'm having trouble in getting the value of the variables selPractice and selLaw

Comment: Michal, just realised it isn't working because I have two instances of the filter on the page. Anyway to be more specific when targeting the selPractice.val()||selLaw.val()?? Thanks

Comment: worked it out thanks for the help, your version was correct as asked so giving it the green tick